# Simple SQL logic validation

Tags: sql

I would like to kindly ask more experience developers to give me a quick evaluation of really simple sql relation logic. I am very new on the field of databases so I don't want to make logic mistake which when found will cause me to rewrite the whole thing.

So here's the thing

I have a few products, let's say a fridge, washing machine and microwave.
To every item belong a few files: manual, quick-start guide, photos etc.

My implementation in database bases on following scheme:

**1. Table 1: Product**
columns here are:

1. name
2. description

**2. Table 2: File**

1. name
2. description
3. file
4. **product (Foreign Key)**

So basically I just make the connection between file and the product by giving every file a product it belongs to.

It seems a little bit counterintuitive tough yet I don't really know why.

Hence this logic is base of the whole system I wanted to ask if I didnt make some simple mistake here.

I guess that for someone experienced it will be obvious how it should be done.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can a given file be associated with more than one product?

Comment: Yes, that might happen

Answer (score 1):

Given that files and products may have a many-to-many relationship, the typical way to handle this is via the use of a *junction* table:

```
product_file (product_id, file_id)
```

The sole purpose of this table is to maintain relationships between products and their files.  But note that none of the metadata is actually stored here.  Instead, the metadata is stored in the following slightly modified file and product tables:

```
product (id, name, description)
file (id, name, description)
```

To see how this works, here is a query which finds the names of all files associated with a certain product:

```
SELECT
    f.name
FROM file f
INNER JOIN product_file pf
    ON f.id = pf.file_id
INNER JOIN product p
    ON pf.product_id = p.id
WHERE
    p.name = 'some product';
```

Comment: +1 : I'd add as extra information that `product_file (product_id, file_id)` primary key is the composition of both foreign keys

Answer (score 0):

You might look for the following solution, or similar:

1. Product (ProductId, Name, Description)
2. CoverItem (CoverItemId, Name, Description)
3. File (ProductId, CoverItemId, File)

Let's say you have a fridge (ProductId=1) and a washing machine (ProductId=2).

As additional ("cover" or whatever term you like) items you define the following: manual (CoverItemId=1) and quick-start guide (CoverItemId=2).

This doesn't make any meaningful information so far, but now you should have a repository of your items you can use.

At last, you insert data to the File table, which connects a product with the cover-item. As an example, (ProductId=1, CoverItemId=1, File="D:\SomeFolder\FridgeManual.txt") would mean that there's a manual for a frigde in the path "D:\SomeFolder\FridgeManual.txt".

HTH

Comment: As stated in comments, the relation between file and product is 1,n - 1,n

Comment: @Cid: Q: "Can a given file be associated with more than one product?" A: "Yes, that might happen".This gives n:n relation between the attribute (cover item) and product. And the answer supports that, assuming there is a file logically inside the product-attribute relation. The answer assumes that OP wanted to model that but didn't know exactly how to describe the problem. There's a lot of such examples here on SO.